# how to find latest folder based on folder name in format 20180828_021335 in java

Tags: java, file, directory

my folder name is coming in below format
yyyyMMdd_HHmmss
my output is

```
20180828_021335
20180828_021330
20170828_011330
20180828_1211330
```

how do i create regex to find latest folder name(latest folder created) in java

i had written below code but it displays folder name based on lastModified but i wish to get folder name based on folder name which is coming `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss` format. i want regex to search latest folder based on folder name

```
String getLatestFolderPath(String path) {
    File dir = new File(path);
    File max = null;
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
         if (file.isDirectory()
                 && (max == null || max.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
             max = file;
         }
    }
    return max.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Is using regex the right approach? Also, please share your current implementation

Comment: @anup please edit your post with the code you put in your comment.

Comment: In your case, time order and alphabetical order are the same -> just sort the strings and take the last one.

Comment: You can solve this problem by String.compareTo method. Find the largest string in a single iteration.

Comment: i had written below code but it displays folder name based on lastModified but i wish to get folder name based on folder name which is coming 
 yyyyMMdd_HHmmss  format i want regex to search latest folder based on folder name
    String getLatestFolderPath(String path)
 {
  File dir = new File(path);
     File max = null;
     for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
         if (file.isDirectory() && (max == null || max.lastModified() < file.lastModified())) {
             max = file;
         }
     }
  return max.toString();
  }

Comment: Why do yo insist on using regex for a problem that can be solved easily by using String.compareTo()? Or do you have other files/directories with names that do not match the pattern you mentioned?

Comment: Thanks for the code in response to the requests in the comments. I put it in the question for you. Supplementary information is always best added in the question, use [the edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52082343/edit). And code so much more since it is unreadable in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
public static Optional<String> getLatestFolderPath(String dirPathName) throws IOException {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd_HHmmss");
    Path dirPath = Paths.get(dirPathName);
    Optional<Path> op = Files.list(dirPath)
            .filter(Files::isDirectory)
            .max(Comparator.comparing(p 
                    -> LocalDateTime.parse(p.getFileName().toString(), formatter)));
    return op.map(Path::toString);
}
```

IMHO a regular expression has no place in your task. Instead I am parsing the date and time in the file name into a `LocalDateTime` and picking the latest. This also gives a validation of your file names. In fact, since the last one of your example directories has a digit too many, it will cause a `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20180828_1211330' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 15`.

I am using some modern stuff like the modern file API, the stream API and an `Optional`. You don’t need these to implement the basic idea, I just preferred to write the code this way. If you need help filtering out what you want from what you don’t want, please follow up in a comment.